# Reputation change text is not centered vertically inside green block in Android Chrome

Tags: bug, reputation, design, top-bar, android

In Chrome on Android 7.0 reputation change in topbar is not aligned vertically (i.e. shifted to the top):

> [image: android]

In Chrome on iOS reputation change looks fine:

> [image: ios]

Comment: That's not the only thing out of alignment [link to OCD inducing image]

Comment: @Catija the lower is more centered than the upper :)

Comment: @Catija it depends on what device I’m using. For the current bug report iOS image looks much better than Android one. And I mean centering the text inside green block, not the entire block within icon.