# Achievement number is off-center with 4+ digits

Tags: bug, design, achievements-dialog

I recently got my first association bonus, which led to a +1000 reputation being shown in my history (for the 10 sites I am a part of).

However, the `+1005` text was not centered properly.

[image: Picture of issue]

Looking at the picture it appears to be optimized for the `1005` (notice how the number is in the center), putting the `+` off to the left.

If it were moved a few pixels to the right, it would be in the center

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reputation change text is not centered vertically inside green block in Android Chrome](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311697/reputation-change-text-is-not-centered-vertically-inside-green-block-in-android)

Comment: @älёxölüt that's about the *vertical* part of the centering, this is about the *horizontal* part.

Comment: @älёxölüt this issue is about horizontal alignment, your proposed duplicate is about vertical alignment.

Comment: This is an edge case not worth spending any time on, imo.

Comment: @Glorfindel true. I will retract my close vote then.

Comment: @Stijn Have to agree with you here - it's not like it detracts from the functionality at all. It's an edge case that, even when hit, causes a minor aesthetic issue at best.